# Hibernate: Get a list of top level categories from Store items

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hql

I have the following entities in my Hibernate application:-

`Store, Item, Category` with the following relations

`Store` has a one-to-many relationship with `Item`

`Category` has a many-to-many relationship with other Categories (i.e A parent category has child categories)

`Item` has a many-to-many relationship with categories which have the same parent category.

I want to have a list of the top-level categories that a store has its items in.

I tried this HQL query but it returns only one top level category

`String queryString = "select c.parentCategory from Category c where :store in elements(c.items)";`

List categories = getSession().createQuery(queryString).setEntity("store", store).list();

Please help me solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it at both logic level and ORM level, not just at ORM level.

Firstly, add relationship: store has a one-to-many relationship with Category
Secondly, add a pre-processor before insert/update/delete a Item for adding or removing Categories in store-level.

```
public void preProcessForItemInserting(Item item){
    Store store = getStoreDao().get( item.getStoreId() );
    Set<Category> storeCategories = store.getCategories();
    Set<Category> itemCategories = item.getCategories();
    storeCategories.addAll( itemCategories );
    getStoreDao().save( store );
}

//it is a little bit more complex than inserting logic
public void preProcessForItemUpdating(Item item){...}

//it is a little bit more complex than inserting logic
public void preProcessForItemDeleting(Item item){...}
```

To summarize, This is classic problem about data-oriented design and appliction-oriented design. we can tune our app in both aspects depending on requeirement instead of just data modeling, or just application optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar before but with a slight simplification. If a category can only have one parent you could model it as:

```
@Entity
public class Category

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Category> childCategories;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parentCategoryId", nullable = true)
private Category parent;
```

Finding the top level categories is then a simple case of finding the categories where the parent is null.

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Category where parent is NULL")
```

This worked for my needs but would require the limitation that categories can only have a single parent.

Comment: Thanks @Alex but my problem goes a little further. I want the list to contain only the top level categories of the store's items, that is, the parent categories returned should each have at least one child category which contains the particular store's items. Do you have any idea on solving it?